# Ошибка в сортировке выбором по 2 полям

Tags: c++, c, сортировка

Функция принимает массив экземпляров структуры и количество экземпляров, и сортирует выбором этот массив по 2 полям(`nomer` и `sname`  ) по убыванию, но сортировка не происходит, все время в условие передаются одни и те же поля, в чём ошибка?

```
int SelectSort(contact *buf, int NumEl)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NumEl - 1; i++)
    {
        int i_min = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < NumEl; j++)
        {
            if (strncmp(buf[i_min].nomer, buf[j].nomer, 2) >= 0)
            {
                if (strcmp(buf[i_min].sname, buf[j].sname) >= 0)
                    i_min = j;
            }
        }
        if (i_min != i)
        {
            swap(buf[i], buf[i_min]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: проверьте логику сравнения. Вы считаете что элемент меньше, если у него и номер и название меньше. Так и задумано?

Comment: Если я сортирую по номеру и внутри одинаковых номеров сортировка по алфавиту, разве не такое сравнение должно быть?

Comment: нет. Вы оба параметра сразу сравниваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте при сортировке ОДНУ функцию сравнения.

В вашем случае это что-то вроде

```
int ContactCmp(const contact& a, const contact& b)
{
    int res = strncmp(a.nomer, b.nomer, 2);
    if (res) return res;
    return strcmp(a.sname, b.sname);
}
```

Впрочем, мне кажется, что я это уже вам писал, нет?

Comment: то есть в цикле по j если функция вернула >0 то i_min = j; я правильно поняла?

Comment: Если эта функция вернула >0, то a > b. Если меньше, то меньше.